# angularjs | date input not showing ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

date input is not showing the date until the user change it

```
// showing the date
<p>{{someDate | date}}</p>

// not showing the date. instead showing mm/dd/yyyy.  
// but value will change when use change is
<input type="date" ng-model="someDate">
```

[example code in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yasig/1/edit)

## it IS working on version **1.3.0-beta.3**, but

I need it to work on stable version 1.2.14.
is it possible?

Comment: it works if you use `<input type='text'>`. Can you use bootstraps datepicker instead of the native html5 type='date'?

Comment: It is not working for me on AngularJS 1.3.0-rc.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created a simple directive to enable standard `input[type="date"]` form elements to work correctly with AngularJS ~1.2.16.

Please look here for details:
https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-date

And here's the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/F2LcY/2/

Hope it helps!

Comment: why is the directive adding a month to the initialized date?

Comment: @PilotBob well, it shouldn't. Please create an issue and attach a Plunk to demonstrate the problem. I will try to fix it as soon as possible. Thanks )

Comment: Here is what I see when I view the jsfiddle linked above. You initialize the date to March 19th but I see April 19. http://screencast.com/t/WJmhhSx65

Comment: @PilotBob I think you are confused with the Date object API. When you instantiate a new Date object in the JavaScript the month value is zero-based, not one-based. So the 3 is actually an April (3 + 1 = 4). Please see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  Don't ask me why JavaScript creators decided to do such a weird thing ))

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if that was the issue, but then thought, no, that would be a most stupid API.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is you must upgrade to angularjs 1.3 or newer. Details in [angular.js/pull/5864](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5864). [The commit implementing this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/46bd6dc88de252886d75426efc2ce8107a5134e9) is pretty large to try to backport to 1.2 IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the someDate scope variable from string **to Date format** and then if you use input type="**date**" ng-model="someDate" . This solved my problem .