# Date format when editing a record retrieved from db using an HTML5 input type=date

Tags: javascript, php, sql, angularjs, date

I have a list of records with a button next to it that when you click on it, it opens a form with data retrieved from the database for that record.

The API sends a JSON object retrieved from the database with a simple SELECT * FROM...

The problem I have is that I can't get the date to be loaded in the input type=date because apparently it's a string - that's the output I get when I do a `console.log(typeof(request.projSched1ExpDate))`.

This is the obvious input :

```
<input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm inputCell"
       ng-model="request.projSched1ExpDate" required />
```

How can I do that please ?

Comment: Considering this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193338/angularjs-inputtype-date-not-showing-value-on-load?rq=1 I add that I'm using version v1.4.0 of AngularJS

Comment: I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666343/angularjs-date-input-not-showing-ng-model-value?noredirect=1&lq=1. It was in 2014 but it seems to be working. Is it still the right answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from **String** to **Date** object and then store to your model like: `$scope.request.projSched1ExpDate = new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z');`

Here it the working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/2lMNGrRQ3TLCBRWDLgrT?p=preview

Here you can find how to convert to **Date** object from string:
[Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)