# HTML5 AngularJS Input Date Not Binding

Tags: angularjs, html

Trying to bind date to input, but it is not binding:

```
<body ng-app>    
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="dateString"/>     
    <br/>{{ dateString }}
     <br/><input type="date" ng-model="date1"/>    
    <br/>{{ date1 }}
</div>
</body>

function MainCtrl($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.dateString = "2015-08-11T00:00:00";
    $scope.date1 = new Date("2015-08-11");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47fLdefo/

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it may be your version of angular. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666343/angularjs-date-input-not-showing-ng-model-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a few things need clarifying as the other answers have glossed over it. The issue is not directly module definition (whilst that is an issue in itself).

The issue is support for using inputs with a type of `date` was not added until `v1.3` according to this [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6630#issuecomment-37213788) however your using `v1.0.2`.

If you want to use inputs with the native date picker you will need to upgrade your version of Angular.

Also using a type of `date` the model value must be a date object not a string representation according the the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

There are other options if you can't upgrade such as BootStraps date picker however.

Answer (score 3):

Your jsfiddle contains error. You forgot to define module. see [here](https://jsbin.com/xoyanutale/edit?html,js,console,output). It is working. Another thing you can not bind a string to a `date`. `string` has to be converted into date before binding by `new Date(yourDateString)`.

```
$scope.dateString = "2015-08-11T00:00:00";
```

Above should be changed by following

```
$scope.dateString = new Date("2015-08-11T00:00:00");
```

**Edit:** I did not notice that your angular version is 1.0.2. input type date is not there. Try to upgrade your angular.

[See](https://jsbin.com/kokacoyela/1/edit?html,js,console,output) date is not binding in 1.0.2

Comment: Problem is that you're using angular 1.4, OP is using 1.0.2.